# Issue on dna sequence in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

i have an image and for that image pixels i need to form or generate a dna sequence.
here for an image each 2 pixels are assigned for dna bases.
that is if the values of image(1,1)=1 and image(1,2)=1 then it should be assigned to A.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: i want a  matlab code inorder to generate a dna sequence as i am getting errors.

Comment: Uh. no. sorry. We aren't here to do your homework. Why don't you show us what you have already tried? BTW, what you're asking for requires specific domain knowledge. Unless someone here has worked with DNA sequencing, no one will be able to help you.

Comment: If you want somebody to help you, please provide an example image (if you can't upload images, upload them somewhere else and provide a link). Then show us the code you are using (try to only include what is needed, or where you are getting errors), and describe the errors you are getting. Otherwise nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

My strategy would be:

- Linearize your image
- Loop over pairs of element
- Define a unique value that represents your pair
- Choose your output letter based on this value

Here is an exemple:

```
% Get random image
Img = randi(2,[10 10])-1

% Prepare output
Out = '';

% Read the image columnwise
for i = 1:2:numel(Img)

    switch 2*Img(i) + Img(i+1)

        case 0      % [0 0]
            Out(end+1) = 'A';

        case 1      % [0 1]
            Out(end+1) = 'T';

        case 2      % [1 0]
            Out(end+1) = 'G';

        case 3      % [1 1]
            Out(end+1) = 'C';

    end
end

disp(Out);
```

Of course, you will have to adapt it a little bit according to your needs.

Hope this helps,